# Google/Typekit Webfont-Loader does not detect non-ASCII fonts

Tags: javascript, variables, callback, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm using the [Google webfont loader](https://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html), but I can't get the `fontactive` callback to work.  The font is rendering on the page, but for some reason the callback isn't firing. (Instead it waits for 5 seconds and then the `fontinactive` callback fires.) I suspect the problem is in how I'm declaring the two variables to the function.

**Edit:** The problem may have to do with the font, not how I'm declaring the variable. The font-loader sucessfully detects when the "STIXGeneral" font family loads, which contains regular letter characters.

*Documentation of the `fontactive` callback is [here](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html#Events).  I haven't been able to find any examples of using the `fontactive` callback.*

I've posted a copy of my code below.

***From Javascript:***

```
WebFont.load({
    custom: {
        families: [ 'STIXSizeOneSym' ],
        urls: ['resources/stix-fonts/STIX-fonts.css']
    },
    fontactive: function(stixsizeonesym, n4) { alert("1") },
    fontinactive: function(stixsizeonesym, n4) { alert("2") },
    inactive: function() { alert("10") }
});
```

***From STIX-fonts.css:***

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'STIXSizeOneSym';
    src: url('STIXSizOneSymBol-webfont.eot');
    src: url('STIXSizOneSymBol-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('STIXSizOneSymBol.otf') format('opentype'),
          url('STIXSizOneSymBol-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

Comment: If you think it might be the second variable, why not simply try it out? Please let us know if you solved your problem another way.

Comment: @Replete - The second variable (`n4` above) is used to specify the weight and style of the font which is to be loaded.  (For example, n4 specifies a roman style with weight of 400--which is usually the default for a font.)  The reason I speculated that the `n4` variable might be the issue here is because I have no way of determining what the STIXSizeOneSym font's weight and style actually are.  (If you have a Mac, you might try using FontForge to read the font's declared weight and style. I can't do that because I broke my Rosetta installation.)

Comment: @Replete (continued) - Still, I suspect that the issue here is not due to using an incorrect variable, but because the "STIXSizeOneSym" font does not include any letter or number glyphs.  Using `n4` works for other STIX fonts that include alpha-numeric characters. And no, I haven't found any solution.

Comment: @Replete (continued) - You might try testing every variable combination that the Google Webfont loader allows, but since I don't believe that's the issue, I haven't spent the time coding 40+ different combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm one of the developers of the webfontloader. We are currently using an ASCII string to detect whether or not a font has loaded. So if your font does not include the characters "BESbswy" the webfontloader won't be able to detect it. We're working on adding support for configurable test strings (so you can include some characters from the Unicode range your font supports.) I've opened an issue for this on the webfontloader repository (https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader/issues/104).

As a temporary solution you can compile your own version of the webfontloader that adds characters from your font to the test string. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: How would I go about compiling my own version of the webfont loader to use a different test string?

Answer (score 2):

I try to use the loader on a Chinese Font "cwTeXHei" downloaded from [Google Early Access](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess).

I spent an afternoon and finally make the fontactive works using the follow codes:

```
WebFontConfig = {
  custom: {
    families: ['ChineseCustomFont'],
    testStrings: {
      'ChineseCustomFont': '\uE003\uE005'
    },
  },
  timeout: 8000
};
(function() {
  var wf = document.createElement('script');
  wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.3/webfont.js';
  wf.type = 'text/javascript';
  wf.async = 'true';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
```

**Points to noted:**

1. Use webfont loader >1.5.0 for support of "testStrings"
2. Use '\uE003\uE005' as "testStrings", I tried '\u9ED1' but not works and I haven't figure out why
3. change timeout since chinese font files are large, default is 5000

Hope it helps someone too!

Answer (score 0):

Have the same prob and did not find any solution yet. It affects only a few fonts, i.e. Bree, or Playfair. My suspicion is that it has something to do with webkit progressively downloading fonts. It seems "fontinactive" is fired *immediately*. I ended up with some complicated Javascript stuff, checking the dimensions of a hidden container in an interval :/

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem is the same as mine.  My problem was cross-browser.  I think the reason I had a problem with the STIX fonts was because they did not contain a standard set of ASCII characters.