# "BESb에swy/ BESbswy" string incorrectly showing in Google search result

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, typekit

My Drupal site's top three Google keywords are besb, swy and 에 . I need to find a way to remove these keywords from the site.

My problem is that these words do not exist on the site, and I can't see them in the source and cannot find any reference to it in our code.

[This site](http://www.noisylittlemonkey.com/blog/what-is-this-korean-character-appearing-in-my-google-webmaster-tool/) says that its a bug with Typekit fontloader plugins.

I have checked the link they refer to [this site](http://tomjn.com/2012/09/13/typekit-besbswy/) which would probably be useful if I was using WordPress or the TinyMCE editor, however I am not using either. The site is built in Drupal.

I have been through the following questions on Stack Overflow, none of these are addressing the issue.

- [Google/Typekit Webfont-Loader does not detect non-ASCII fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879469/google-typekit-webfont-loader-does-not-detect-non-ascii-fonts)
- [PHP preg_replace BESbswy ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118999/php-preg-replace-besbswy-ckeditor)
- [Why is "BESbewy" appearing in my site spans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944187/besbewy-what-the-heck-is-this)

I have searched though our code and through code we are pulling in and cannot find a way to fix this.

A quick Google search of BESbswy shows hundreds of sites displaying the same symptoms.

UPDATE:

On our site we are using some fonts from fonts.com.
They include a script from fast.fonts.com/jsapi with a big unique identifier.

After running it through an online beautifier I found what I belive to be the culprit, unforunately I cannot figure out a solution from my end

Line 631:

```
    la = "BESb\uc5d0swy";
```

I belive that string is whats causing my problem and the problem exhibited by the many other sites on google and duckduckgo

Further down there is the following code

```
       R.prototype.Wa = function() {
        setTimeout(C(function() {
            this.ta()
        }, this), 25)
    };
```

According to the suggestions from [this site](http://tomjn.com/2012/09/13/typekit-besbswy/)  it looks like fonts.com need to adjust the timeout here to correct this issue.

I am still hoping someone else has a cleaner and simpler solution to this issue.

Comment: How odd, [it is a thing at DDG](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=BESbswy) too.

Comment: This is a test string for font loading. When correctly loaded the string is removed. So fix your font loading and it will go away.